# adding multiple tables/CSVs to SQLITE file using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I am using SQLAlchemy and Pandas to set up a SQLITE file.  I have four CSVs as dataframes and I want want all four in the SQLITE using the 
df.to_sql("file.csv", engine)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",index_col=0)
df.head()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db/file.sqlite")
df.to_sql("file", engine)
```

Comment: Is your question cut-off? Please edit post to complete text and relay any errors/undesired results.

Comment: No cut-off.  I'm just showing how I have added one csv to the sqlite.  Wondering how to continue to add CSVs (i have 3 more)

Comment: Look at [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) arguments.